# Casting an Item Collection from a listbox to a generic list

Tags: c#, list, casting, listbox

I want to find a better way of populating a generic list from a checkedlistbox in c#.

I can do the following easily enough:

```
List<string> selectedFields = new List<string>();

foreach (object a in chkDFMFieldList.CheckedItems) {
         selectedFields.Add(a.ToString());
         }
```

There must be a more elagent method to cast the CheckedItems collection to my list.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Try this (using System.Linq):**

`OfType()` is an extension method, so you need to use `System.Linq`

```
List<string> selectedFields = new List<string>();
selectedFields.AddRange(chkDFMFieldList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>());
```

Or just do it in one line:

```
List<string> selectedFields = chkDFMFieldList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to know the type of the ItemCollection? So the method works with any ItemCollection without knowing the type

Comment: "OfType<string>()" --  I learned something new today! Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 17):

This is not exactly the answer to your requirement, but posting a more general answer. You could do it in a variety of ways:

1)

```
T[] items = new T[lb.Items.Count];
lb.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
var lst = new List<T>(items);
```

2) looping and adding using `foreach` as you mentioned.

3) using Linq

```
var lst = lb.Items.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

4) or

```
var lst = lb.Items.OfType<T>().ToList();
```

When I did some performance testing like below, I found copying to array method the fastest while the Linq methods slower. Of course in real world scenarios these wouldnt matter. I prefer the 3rd method (Linq) for readability.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Action();
}
MessageBox.Show((DateTime.Now - d).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

For an iteration of 10000 times run multiple times with about 300 items in list box,

1) ~100ms

2) ~150ms

3) ~250ms

4) ~260ms

Comment: Digging in the vast archive of StackOverflow... @nawfal, the advantage of solution **4)** is that if you have different items in your collection (e.g. menu with `MenuItem`s and `Separator`s) `OfType<T>` will simply choose only `<T>` items from the collection, while **3)** will throw `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to LINQ then there isn't a more elegant way since you're performing a second operation on the list items (calling `ToString()`) in addition to populating the selectedFields collection.