# Most succinct way to convert ListBox.items to a generic list

Tags: c#, generics, collections, type-conversion

I am using C# and targeting the .NET Framework 3.5. I'm looking for a small, succinct and efficient piece of code to copy all of the items in a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) to a `List<String>` (Generic [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)).

At the moment I have something similar to the below code:

```
        List<String> myOtherList =  new List<String>();
        // Populate our colCriteria with the selected columns.

        foreach (String strCol in lbMyListBox.Items)
        {
            myOtherList.Add(strCol);
        }
```

Which works, of course, but I can't help but get the feeling that there must be a better way of doing this with some of the newer language features. I was thinking of something like the [List.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method but this only applies to Generic Lists and not [ListBox.ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx) collections.

Comment: What are the objects in the list box?

Comment: Sorry - should have explicitly stated that they were Strings.

Comment: an extension method is what I like

Comment: not the most succinct, but a variety of options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400787/661933)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting an Item Collection from a listbox to a generic list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471595/casting-an-item-collection-from-a-listbox-to-a-generic-list)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

A bit of LINQ should do it:-

```
 var myOtherList = lbMyListBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
```

Of course you can modify the Type parameter of the Cast to whatever type you have stored in the Items property.

Comment: Is `List<String> Mylist = new List<String>(lbMyListBox.Items.Cast<String>());` better or it makes no difference? The question, I guess, is if, this way, you avoid the creation of another list or not.

Answer (score 31):

The following will do it (using Linq):

```
List<string> list = lbMyListBox.Items.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

The [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) call will ensure that only items in the listbox's items that are strings are used.

Using [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx), if any of the the items are not strings, you will get an exception.

Comment: Of course by using OfType the resulting list may be missing items.  If the set of items are expected to be of a specific type use Cast since it doesn't hide a bug where the wrong types have been added to the ListBox (which is easy to do).  Additionaly OfType will skip items that have a Conversion operator to the expected output type whereas Cast will invoke the converter operator.

Comment: Yes. I should really have said "items that are not castable to strings". The OfType issue is a good point, but if the ListBox should only contain strings, it will stop a crash in the case where something else erroneously creeps in

Comment: I'm expecting the listbox to be filled with strings but in the case of a non-string object being placed in the listbox, I would rather silently skip that item than cause an exception and deal with that exception in much the same way.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
List<string> myOtherList = (from l in lbMyListBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>() select l.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
myOtherList.AddRange(lbMyListBox.Items);
```

EDIT based on comments and DavidGouge's answer:

```
myOtherList.AddRange(lbMyListBox.Items.Select(item => ((ListItem)item).Value));
```

Comment: it will give the following error: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Comment: ObjectCollection is IEnumerable but not IEnumerable<T> which is required by AddRange.

Comment: this doesnt even compile for me

Answer (score 2):

You don't need more. You get List of all values from Listbox

```
private static List<string> GetAllElements(ListBox chkList)
        {
            return chkList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList<string>();
        }
```