# How do I populate a List<String> with values already present in Listbox control in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, listbox

I have a listbox which has a couple of values and is already populated (from user input). Later in my program I want to take these values from the listbox and populate them to a List collection.

One of the approach is of course to iterate through the items of the listbox and populate the List collection one by one (in a loop) using Add method.

But is there a better more efficient way to do this in one shot meaning all the items of the listbox get copied over to a List collection.

I also looked at the AddRange method but that doesnt seem to help.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Databinding would do this automatically for you.

Comment: @LarsTech OP is using WinForms; a bit cumbersome in that setting.

Comment: @AaronMcIver Respectfully, not sure I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it must be a `List<string>`, I think you will have to enumerate the items and add them to a list (since you are concerned about the efficiency of LINQ).  If you can use a `string[]`, you could use the `CopyTo` method:

```
string[] destination = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(destination, 0);
```

Comment: @Patrick, this will throw an exception if the `ListBox` contains items that aren't `string`.  I realized this after posting - if your `ListBox` can contain non-string types, you would have to use `CopyTo()` with an `object[]`.  At that point, this probably wouldn't be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessarily more efficient (in terms of speed/memory), but you can save some typing via LINQ:

```
List<string> items = listBox.Items.Cast<object>()
                            .Select(item => item.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: No less typing than a simple `foreach(object item in list.Items) items.Add(item.ToString());` ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Once you add the constructor + declaration, I believe it is... (but not much ;) )  - Just typed them out, it's 8 chars shorter + looks better on one line...

Comment: Yes - As stated on my question - this is what is easier to do but if my listbox has over 200 K items for example - doing this can drag the program down. Hence was looking for a copy method (as a whole) versus adding each element through an iterator.

Comment: @Patrick There is no direct "copy" method - anything is going to require iterating the collection.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, but I think this would be less typing:  `var list = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();`

Comment: @adrift That can throw if the types weren't actually strings.  You can (technically) put any object into ListBox.Items...

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a more *efficient* way.

If anything existed it would simply abstract away what you will be doing anyways via an extension method or other means and could have the possibility of making your code less readable.

The `CopyTo` method does exist via the `ObjectCollection` on the `Items` property which could then be LINQ'ed to a `List<T>`.

```
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        object[] items = new object[lb.Items.Count];
        lb.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemCollection` class implements `IList`, you'll need to cast the items in the collection to String since it's not a generic collection, but you already have a "List collection" of the items.

If you really need a copy of the items in collection then no, there isn't going to be a more efficient way. There are plenty of ways to implement syntatic sugar so that the code is more concise, but ultimately they will *all* be iterating over the items and creating copies to be added to a new collection.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate of: [Most succinct way to convert ListBox.items to a generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565504/most-succinct-way-to-convert-listbox-items-to-a-generic-list)

If you're copying from the listbox, what is populating that list? It might be a better option to go about it that way, versus taking 200k items and moving it over. if you're taking all items in a listbox, populate the List at the same time.

On that note.. really? 200k items in a listbox?. That right there seems a little over the top in a real world application.

Foreach(...) loops are very expensive - even when compiled into IL: http://diditwith.net/2006/10/05/PerformanceOfForeachVsListForEach.aspx

If you are unable to work with LINQ (your using <= VS 2005), this is one of the easier methods of doing it.

```
    string[] items = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
    listBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
    List<string> list = new List<string>(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron McIver, your own method is a bit faster in my opinion. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400787/661933) for some performance testing I have done.