# Convert C# SurfaceListBox into a JSON array

Tags: c#, json, listbox, pixelsense

I'm working with the MS Surface table called Samsung SUR40 and use the language C# in MS Visual Studio 2010 Express.

What do i want to develop?

An API that records the Surface input and parses these to AS3 using sockets.

How i want to do this?

I want to convert a Surface listbox (i think this is the same as the usual WPF listbox) into a JSON array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [convert Listbox item collection into List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471595/casting-an-item-collection-from-a-listbox-to-a-generic-list) or array, and then use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to serialize List into JSON.