# How to get the CheckedListBox Selected Items into List<X>...?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am having a List of type X. X is a Property Level Class. 
Now on an event i need the CheckedListBox Selected Items into another List.

How to get the output...??
The code i tried is given below...

```
public void Initialize(List<X> x1)
{
        chkList.DataSource = x1;
        chkList.DisplayMember = "MeterName"; // MeterName is a property in Class X
        chkList.ValueMember = "PortNum"; // PortNum is a property in Class X
}

private void Click_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

List<X> x2 = new List<X>();
// Here I want to get the checkedListBox selected items in x2;
// How to get it...???

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting an Item Collection from a listbox to a generic list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471595/casting-an-item-collection-from-a-listbox-to-a-generic-list)

Answer (score 23):

you can try the following

```
 List<X>  x2 =  chkList.CheckedItems.OfType<X>().ToList();
```

or cast as object

```
List<object>  x2 = chkList.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: +1 this works fine, I see no reason to add my foreach based answer :)

Comment: actually i am using DevExpress so the above solution wont work there. But it gave me a spark to get my solution... tanx buddy..

Comment: @RavishankarN you can use `Cast` instead of `OfType` to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that works for me:

```
List<X> x2 = new List<X>();
x2 = chkList.CheckedItems.Cast<X>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer

```
private void Click_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

List<X> x2 = new List<X>();
foreach (X item in chkList.CheckedItems)
    {
        x2.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] miList = chkList.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().Select(li => li.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another Option

```
List<X> lst = new List<X>(chkList.CheckedItems.Cast<X>());
```