# Filling a List with checked items in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, list, deprecated, checkedlistbox

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471595/casting-an-item-collection-from-a-listbox-to-a-generic-list), I am trying to fill a list of integers with the checked objects (integers) in a CheckedListBox as follows:

```
protected System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox channelCheckedListBox;
private List<int>    selectedChannels;

//some code

selectedChannels.AddRange(channelCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.OfType<int>().ToList());
```

However, Visual Studio is throwing me an error. Is it me, or is the `OfType()` method depreciated? It does not appear to be present in the [CheckedItemCollection type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). How can I achieve the same thing in a nice, concise manner using .NET Framework 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OfType should still be available and as far as I can see it isn't marked as Obsolete in the .NET Framework version 4.5. It is an extension method though, so you will need to import the `System.Linq` namespace in your class by adding `using System.Linq;` to the top of your class and ensuring the reference is added to your project.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't see that before in the original question. Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that extension methods were a thing. I have to wait a few minutes to choose best answer.

Comment: No problem! Here is the Microsoft write up extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx for further reading. They can be really useful in a company framework for common tasks. And on the flip side: they are tempting to over use, which can really clutter up existing object intellisense.